# 650 + 150 = 850 in jQuery? sum of two values return weird values

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this code:

```
var navWidth = jQuery("ul#navi"), 
    phoneWidth = jQuery("div#phone-number"), 
    diff = navWidth.outerWidth() + phoneWidth.outerWidth();

console.log(navWidth.outerWidth());
console.log(phoneWidth.outerWidth());
console.log(diff);
```

and it shows in console

> 650 150 850

can anyone tell me why it shows 850 as 650 + 150 ?

Comment: Do you have borders, margins and padding??? :)

Comment: Take a look to them using browser debugging tools for layout...margins, padding, anchors...you should post more than this.

Comment: that wouldn't explain the console.log

Comment: Can you post this on jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure if the values of margins and padding etc. should matter. The value of the outerWidth() function should be consistent between the line where diff is defined and console.log.

Comment: Please reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @dystroy: The `,`s make it so it's all one `var` statement.

Comment: `console.log(navWidth.outerWidth(),phoneWidth.outerWidth(),diff);` will make you understand better

Comment: Is this code **really** the code that is causing the problem for you?? Or did you omit something? Because I've created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQFXP/) and it works fine.

Comment: Try `parseInt(navWidth.outerWidth()) + parseInt(phoneWidth.outerWidth())`

Comment: please show some more research effort

Comment: The phone div has both left and right paddings, same for the navi div..but does it matter?

Comment: here's where the issue happens: http://teothemes.com/wp/ ... you can check the console log

Comment: Already tried parseInt before and it didn't work

Comment: There is this line : `navWidth.css("width", navWidth.outerWidth()-phoneWidth.outerWidth() );` between allocations and log...

Comment: lol, yeah, you're right. Thank you so much!

Comment: Lol, knew it! You posted an incomplete piece of s... err... code. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have padding or/and margin, this can change your width.

The function .outherWidth() returns the width of the div, including the padding, the border and excluding the margin.

The function .innerWidth() returns the width of the div, including the padding and excluding the border and the margin.

The function .outherWidth(true) returns the width of the div, including the padding and the margin.

The function .width() returns the width of the div, exclusing the padding and margin.

Take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) link.

I hope it can solve your problem.